# If no session found, don't show PHP and HTML code

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, if-statement, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to figure out how to not show certain HTML and PHP code when the user is NOT logged in.

So when no user is logged in I don't want to use this code on my page:

```
<div class="overditcadeau_tekst2">
       <!--Als het cadeau niet van de ingelogde gebruiker is laat een button zien dat heet cadeau aanvragen -->
       <div class="cadeau_aanvragen">
  <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($product["user_id"]) && $_SESSION['user_id'] != $product["user_id"])  : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'Product/cadeaupagina_ontvangen/'.$product_id.'/'. $user_id;?>"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary cw">Ik wil dit cadeau!</button></a>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<!--Als het cadeau van de ingelogde gebruiker is laat een button zien dat heet cadeau bewerken-->
<div class="cadeau_bewerken">
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($product["user_id"]) && $_SESSION['user_id'] == $product["user_id"])  : ?>
    <a class="btn btn-primary ca" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"> Cadeau bewerken </a>
<?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="cadeau_verwijderen">
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($product["user_id"]) && $_SESSION['user_id'] == $product["user_id"])  : ?>
    <a class="btn btn-primary ca" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Delete_ctrl/delete_product_id/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"> Cadeau verwijderen </a>
<?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <!--Als het cadeau van de ingelogde gebruiker is laat aantal geïnteresseerden zien-->
    <div class="aantal_geinteresseerden">
         <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($product["user_id"]) && $_SESSION['user_id'] == $product["user_id"])  : ?>
    <p>Geïnteresseerden:</p>
<?php endif; ?>
    </div>

<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($product["user_id"]) && $_SESSION['user_id'] != $product["user_id"])  : ?>
     <div class="aangeboden_door">   Aangeboden door:   
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'User/userdetails/'.$product['user_id']?>">
          <?php echo $userarray['voornaam'];?>
        </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
</div>

<?php endif; ?> 
</div>
```

I tried to put the code in this if isset function:

```
 <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['user_logged'] = TRUE; )) {
```

And than end it under the code with `}`

But that doesn't work because there is alot of HTML code in it`

Any kind of help is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: "But that doesn't work because there is alot of HTML code in it" — That is not why it doesn't work. Putting a lot of HTML inside an if statement is fine. Follow the guidance at [mcve] in order to track down the real cause of your problem.

Comment: Can you add the results of a `print_r($_SESSION);` to your questions please

Comment: Instead of checking if the user can access a page that judging by your others posts should be entirely secured, why don't you just check in the constructor of the controller if the user is logged in with the same logic, and if not redirect? Also ci had its own way of handling sessions, might want to consider using that as that is what a framework is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you have problem in your session condition

Add this in the start of your code

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_logged']) && $_SESSION['user_logged']== TRUE){ ?>
```

and at the end of file with

```
<?php } ?>
```